# Push notifications working for old application but not on the new one

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, push-notification

I have an application in the appstore that has working push notifications. I created a new app and I am trying to get the notifications working using the same App ID. I made sure that my bundle identifier matches the old app, push notifications are enabled and didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is getting a token. My server is sending the app to Apple's APNS services but didReceiveRemoteNotification is never called. I am testing this with a deployment build.

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {

    print("Failed to register:", error)


func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
   processPushMessage(userInfo)
    print("recieved alert :\(userInfo)");

}


func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {

    profile.reset()
    getObjects()

     print("didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken")

    let tokenChars = UnsafePointer<CChar>(deviceToken.bytes)
    var tokenString = ""

    for i in 0..<deviceToken.length {
        tokenString += String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [tokenChars[i]])
    }



    print("Device Token:", tokenString)
```

}

[image]

Comment: does the app receive push when app is in killed state and you see a banner ?

Comment: I have tried the app in background and foreground and it doesn't send. My app has to be running to trigger the server to send the push

Comment: why does it need to be running ?

Comment: It is sent when a Asterisk call has been connected so I need it open to connect the call.

Comment: i would suggest just trying to use https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher to send a simple push with app being killed, if it is received debug why you dont get push in foreground. Otherwise, debug your provisioning and certificate to see why you dont receive push at all

Comment: A deployment build should be a release build by default, you haven't changed it to be a debug build have you?  - Your server will be using the Apple production environment, it has to as your 1st app is on the app store, but if your new app is a debug build then the pushes would need to be sent on the Apple sandbox environment, not the production environment. BYW having an app trigger a server to send a push back to it seems totally bonkers, unless its actually triggering the server to send a push to the app on a different device.

Answer (score 0):

Have you revoked your certificate. Even if your provisional profile becomes inactive or invalid then also you won't receive notification. Check in your developer portal whether that profile is active or inactive(in-valid).